# How to include specific directories in gtags.conf file

Tags: global, ctags, exuberant-ctags

I work on a big project and want to only get the tags for some of the directories. 
How do I tell gtags to only parse these directories and maybe "exclude" some sub directories within the ones specified?

I looked online but there is not enough documentation on how to construct or modify a gtags.conf file.